# htaccess - extensionless URLs + redirect index to root

Tags: php, .htaccess

There are plently of answers on how to create extensionless URLs and how to redirect index to root. I'm having a hard time combining both in my htaccess file. One always creates a problem with the other. Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

301 redirects

```
domain.com to www.domain.com
domain.com/index.php to www.domain.com
domain.com/index to www.domain.com
www.domain.com/index.php to www.domain.com
www.domain.com/index to www.domain.com

/all-other-pages.php to /all-other-pages
/all-other-pages/ to /all-other-pages (if not a directory)
```

Currently I'm using this:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# REWRITE TO NON-EXTENSION URL

# unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

# redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*[^.#?\ ]+\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.php $1 [R=301,L]

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# REDIRECT TO WWW LOCATION

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index$
RewriteRule ^(.*)index$ /$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
#RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

All seemed well until I tried:
    www.example.com/index.php

This redirects to:

```
 www.example.com/index
```

I didn't keep track of all the variations I've tried, sorry.
This code is copy and pasted which I usually don't like doing especialy when I don't understand the code but I'm afraid I really can't get into learning the instricacies of htaccess and regex at the moment.

There is only one htaccess file that is in document_root, BUT, I will be having a sub-directory where I want the same kind of page redirects to happen.

Thanks for any help,
Barry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your rules in this order:

```
RewriteEngine On

# REDIRECT TO WWW LOCATION
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] 

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index(\.php)?[/?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index(?:\.php)?$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

# redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php[/?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php $1 [R=301,L]

# unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Make sure to test it after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: I have an extra problem as I'm testing locally using easyPHP. Not having my site name encoded in the www redirect code causes problems as locally there is no www. I need to sort that out first before I can test this, how should I change your first two lines of code to accomplish that please? Thank you very much.

Comment: I appreciate your help but this still doesn't do all required. example.com/index doesn't resolve to example.com
example.com/page.php doesn't resolve to example.com/page. I cleared the cache plus I'm changing 301 to 302 while testing. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, the file extension part seems to work perfectly now, even within a sub-directory. Now I just need to sort out the www part in a way that works locally and at my web host. As I say, locally there is no www in the URL, can that be added? If so then I could try your inital code. Thanks again.

Comment: I've added www. to my local virtualhost name now so I can view my local site with the URL www.mysitename_local. When I test without the www. it opens my default search site to search for the URL. Any ideas? I think it's almost there.

Comment: I've slightly modified `www` rule. On my localhost I have an alias as `www.localhost` that just points to `127.0.0.1` like `localhost`. That is how I have tested that `www` rule and it works pretty well.

Comment: I've now tested all variations I can think of and this now seems to be working perfectly, thank you very much.